# STM32 uC after exit DFU mode does not return to normal but has breakpoints

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I'm entering the DFU mode of the STM32 without using the Boot0 physical pin. I do this by sending a command via the UART and switch the uC to DFU mode. I'm using the STM32F042G6U6.

But it doesn't restart when I use the ST tools to exit from DFU mode.

The below code is what I use boot my uC into DFU mode.

```c
#define SYSMEM_RESET_VECTOR         0x1FFFC404 //Offset +4
#define RESET_TO_BOOTLOADER_CODE    0xDEADBEEF
#define BOOTLOADER_STACK_POINTER    0x20001800

void __initialize_hardware_early(void)
{
    *((unsigned long *)0x20001600) =  0xCAFEFEED;

    void (*SysMemBootJump)(void);
    SysMemBootJump = (void (*)(void)) (*((uint32_t *)(SYSMEM_RESET_VECTOR)));

    __set_MSP(BOOTLOADER_STACK_POINTER);
    SysMemBootJump();
}

void dfu_run_bootloader()
{
    *((unsigned long *)0x20001600) = RESET_TO_BOOTLOADER_CODE;
    NVIC_SystemReset();
}
```

`dfu_run_bootloader` is called from within the UART receive function. `__initialize_hardware_early` was placed inside `SystemInit`.

```c
void SystemInit(void)
{
    if (*((unsigned long *)0x20001600) == 0xDEADBEEF) {
        __initialize_hardware_early();
    }
... // The rest of the SystemInit() function
```

After click *"Leave DFU Mode"* I expect the device to return to the normal state. But it doesn't.

[image: Dfuse demo]

When I attach the debugger it reports a breakpoint in two places. Everything as in the pictures below. The device starts to work properly when I click the resume button.

[image: breakpoint 1]

[image: breakpoint 2]

Comment: Have you tried [`STM32CubeProgrammer`](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html) This also can use the DFU mode but is more meant to be used by a user. The DfuSe Demo comes across to me as a demo.

Comment: @TarickWelling I just tried STM32CubeProgrammer and the result surprised me. In this program I can connect to the device and I can operate it without any problems. I still have to check if I can connect with a library STDFU.dll that has been provided by ST. Unfortunately, using the STM32CubeProgrammer I can not test exit from the DFU mode.